# SetPassword is very slow

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices

We are experiencing a performance problem when communicating with the active directory using `System.DirectoryServices. DirectoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password })` sometimes takes 15 seconds. The Service that makes the call is running on the same machine.
What could make it that slow?

Cheers,

bja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified Active Directory replication between sites is functioning properly?  Most attribute changes are passively queued for replication, but password changes are immediately replicated.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to resolve this problem by opening the port 464 on the firewall which is the first attempt by the ADSI API to perform a CRL check on the network for user authentication.

http://www.pc-library.com/ports/tcp-udp-port/464/