# Why does calling SetPassword on a DirectoryEntry takes 60 seconds to succeed?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using the following C# code to set a user's password via the DirectoryEntry class:

```
user.Invoke("SetPassword", password);
```

The code is contained in a DLL.  Loading the DLL and using this code in a service running under a GMSA takes 60 seconds to return, although successfully.  However loading the DLL and using this code from a command line executable works fine - even if I use `psexec` to run the command line under the GMSA.

There's a fair few similar problems reported that I've tried to eliminate by the above testing, e.g. [accessing port 464](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454981/setpassword-is-very-slow#), or [the SetPassword function falling through different mechanisms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/setting-user-passwords-for-ldap-providers).

Why does calling SetPassword on a DirectoryEntry takes 60 seconds to succeed?  Alternatively, what debugging can I do to determine why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Remarks section of the `SetPassword` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-iadsuser-setpassword#remarks), it lists several mechanisms that it tries to set the password, because you need a secure connection to do it. I'm guessing that the first one didn't work, so it has to try 2 or maybe even all three.

The LDAP string used to create `user` could determine how many hoops `SetPassword` has to run through to find an acceptably secure method. Running from a different computer can also make a difference on which mechanisms would work, depending on firewall restrictions or if one of those computers is not joined to the same domain and the other is.

`SetPassword` isn't the only way to set a password. You can do it by setting the `unicodePwd` attribute directly, in the very specific way that [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) describes. That looks like this in C#:

```
user.Properties["unicodePwd"].Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("\"NewPassword\"");
user.CommitChanges();
```

But you have to make sure that you're connecting in a secure way. That's not taken care for you like it is with `SetPassword`. You can either use LDAPS (LDAP over SSL), which requires that the server is using a trusted certificate (notice port 636):

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com:636/CN=SomePerson,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com");
```

Or, if the computer you are running this from is joined to the same domain or a trusted domain, then you can use Kerberos, which is done by passing `AuthenticationTypes.Sealing` in the constructor:

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=SomePerson,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
           , null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing);
```

This is a way of explicitly telling it how to connect securely, rather than letting `SetPassword` try different methods until it finds one. So that might save time.

Comment: This worked to resolve the delay but I never did determine why it was only happening when run as a service.  I know SetPassword wasn't using LDAPS (not configured), but it should've been falling back to Kerberos as the above code ultimately worked.  Calling NetUserSetInfo directly kept failing with a error code of 2245, even the password worked manually or via other mechanisms so who knows.

Comment: It's possible it was trying LDAPS and waiting for it to fail before it moved on to Kerberos. You could figure that out using something like Wireshark, but it's probably not worth the effort. I'm happy to hear you have it working now.

Comment: My suspicion was that LDAPS was failing immediately when run interactively, but timing out when run as a service - I'd already attempted Wireshark (and Process Monitor) but there wasn't an obvious difference in the 60 seconds delay.